# Why my eclipse framework stops working when through a plugin a java application starts and when i exit this application the Eclipse stops

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have implemented an eclipse plugin that it launches a java application when the user clicks at a button.The bug is that the java application stops(the user clicks the exit button) the whole eclipse framework stops working.
Here is the code i am using to launch the java code.

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
       new atag.gui.MainFrame().setVisible(true);
      }
     });
```

the Mainframe is a class that implements Jframe and it is inside a library

Comment: could you give some more details? What are you doing when the user clicks the exit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the other applications code, maybe it says `System.exit(0)`, where a click on the exit button is handled...

A [JFrame can be configured](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29) to "exit on close". Even if it is set to "dispose on close" the VM my terminate after the last displayable (AWT/Swing) window has been closed.

I didn't pay attention on first reading: You are using Swing components inside the eclipse framework: that is ... not a good idea. Plugins should only use the SWT library or use the [SWT-Swing bridge](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html) to show Swing based content.

Comment: Andeas it is the default window frame in java .In fact the code for the X button at the upper right and it is not handled by me